# I need to calculate the latitude/longitude using existing lat/longitude , distance and direction

Tags: java, geolocation, geometry, google-places-api

While integrating google API in Java, I need to calculate another place's lat/long using existing lat/long, distance and direction. How to calculate that point?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Lat/Long does it change?

Comment: @SMA I think he means if you start at a point whose lat/long is known, and you go a certain distance in a certain direction, what's the lat/long of the point you will end up at.

Comment: This is a math question, not a Java question or even a programming question.  If you have the formulas you need but don't know how to express them in a Java program, then you can ask a Java question.

Comment: Yes, this is the math logic only.. but, I cant find any exact method to find out the answer... I think anyone might have faced this problem before..so only I am posting here...

Answer (score 0):

The following PHP code provides the point from `$lat1,$lng1` a distance `$dist` (kms) along a bearing `$brng`.

```
function destination($lat1,$lng1,$dist,$brng){
$alpha = $dist/6371; // km
$lat2 = asin((sin($lat1)*cos($alpha)) +(cos($lat1)*sin($alpha)*cos($brng)) );
$lng2 = $lng1 + atan2(sin($brng)*sin($alpha)*cos($lat1),cos($alpha)-sin($lat1)*sin($lat2));
return array(toDeg($lat2),toDeg($lng2));
}
```

`$lat1,$lng1 & $brng` in radians

```
function toRad($deg) {
// Converts numeric degrees to radians 
    return $deg * pi() / 180;
}
function toDeg($rad){
   return $rad * 180 / pi();
}
```